How to use both HTML2PDF and FPDF in a multipage PDF document
I am trying to create a PDF document that is about 12 pages long. This document includes images as well as information from the database that will need to be pulled through. I am using various scripts from fpdf.org. I would like to use both HTML2pdf.php and fpdf.php to allow me to do multiple functions in one document. I started the document with a class in fpdf called class PDF_CircularText. Can I add a second class for html2pdf halfway through the code when I need it?
This is how I started the document and it works great, but now I want to add an extra class for PDF_HTML(); but still keep PDF_CircularText();
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new PDF_CircularText();

$pdf->AddFont('kids','','kids.php');
$pdf->AddFont('BENETOpti-Black','','BENETOpti-Black.php');

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf ->Image('images/background.png',0, 0, 210, 0, 'PNG');


I'd have thought if you use two separate libraries you'll be forced to end up with two separate documents being created, which you'd then have to find a way to merge. But maybe someone with more in-depth knowledge of these libraries will know differently

Thank you @ADyson. I also hope someone can assist. This is a rather complicated task I am tackling.

It might help if you can clarify the exact goal and your reasons for trying to use two libraries. Have you found there are specific features you need which are only found in each of these libraries, and not in the other?

I don’t think you will be able to “hand off” from one to another. As noted by others, each library assumes it is the document writer so they are controlling objects, references, etc. However, you could try telling html2pdf to start its first page with top margin based off of FPDF’s last text/line/image/etc. bottom, and then use FPDFI to import the outputted document back into the master. That said, after living in this world for a very long time, unless you really need to, I’d strongly encourage keeping the pages separate, and just merging it all in the end.
